# Can't Import Using Absolute Path

Tags: python

I have a very simple test Python 3 project with the following file structure:

```
test/a.py
test/b.py
test/__init__.py
```

[Everywhere I read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951941/python-absolute-import-for-module-in-the-same-directory), people say that in `a.py` I should import `b.py` using an absolute path:

`from test.b import *`

However, when I try I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 1, in <module>
    from test.b import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test.b'
```

I understand that I can import `b.py` using `from b import *`, however this is not what people recommend. They all recommend `from test.b import *`. But I can't get even this simple example to work.

Comment: Is there a `test/__init__.py`?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Fixed that is the question.

Comment: How are you running `a.py`?

Comment: Are you running `a.py` as a script? Then your module search path won't include the parent directory of `test` and it is not findable as a top-level name.

Comment: Is there another way?

Comment: By giving us the information we are asking for, for starters. This is almost certainly a duplicate, this is a common issue (files inside packages should not be used as scripts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common directory structure is like this:

```
test/a.py
test/b.py
test/__init__.py
run.py
```

The main code should be put into `run.py`. When you want to import `a.py` in `run.py`, just write `from test.a import *` or something like that. And if you need to import `b.py` in `a.py`, do as you have been told `from test.b import *`. Then, run `run.py` would get the correct result.

Comment: Ahh I see. So to do `from test.b import *`, `run.py` needs to be a sibling to `test/`. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

As Martijn said in the comment, it depends on how you call `a.py`.
If you call it directly from within the directory by typing `python a.py` you will get the error above.

However, if you call it like that: `python -m test.a` while being one directory above the `test` directory, your import will work just fine.